# Autolayout/ Universal Layout Constraints

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, autolayout, constraints

I have an app with a `Title` and two columns of labels. The issue is that the layout must remain consistent across all iOS devices (iPhones and iPads) and orientations. However, as you can see:

[image: this screenshot]

... I'm not having much luck.

Comment: So what actually is your issue? Can't you divide the width equally between two views? If you go through this tutorial carefully, you'll find what you're looking for: [RayWenderlich: Auto Layout Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/83129/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-swift-part-1)

Comment: You should also take a look in Stack View, released with Xcode 7. It makes the UI design much easier than pure AutoLayout.

Comment: Thank you. The problem is that the two columns are rendered different depending on orientation and device. Usually the 'textone' column is more centred than it ought to be.